# Multiple values are not allowed for plugin option org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:package

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for Android development with Kotlin. I have 5 Android modules in the project: 3 are Java, 2 are Kotlin.

Everything was working fine but after a "Rebuild Project" suddenly I'm getting this error:

```
Information:Kotlin: Kotlin JPS plugin version 1.1.1
Information:Kotlin: Plugin loaded: KotlinAndroidJpsPlugin
Information:Kotlin: Using kotlin-home = /home/user/.IdeaIC2016.3/config/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc
Information:Kotlin: Kotlin Compiler version 1.1.1
Information:javac 1.8.0_91 was used to compile java sources
Information:3/16/17 2:13 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 4s 716ms
Error:Kotlin: Multiple values are not allowed for plugin option org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:package
Plugin "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" usage:
  variant <name;path>        Android build variant (required, multiple)
  package <fq name>          Application package (required)
```

If I remove any Kotlin module, the error goes away.

---

EDIT: building the Kotlin modules separately doesn't throw this error, so I guess this is a Kotlin plugin bug.

Comment: Do you have the same Kotlin version specified in both modules?

Comment: @zsmb13 I only have 1 Kotlin library defined on the project, both modules import this one.

Comment: Could you post your Kotlin `build.gradle` files?

Comment: @Ritave No Gradle, I'm using IntelliJ build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug on Kotlin plugin ([YouTrack reported issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16888)).

> Sharing these settings for reading/writing between different module
>   during JPS build may lead to compiler settings (plugionOptions, in
>   particular) of several modules to be mixed

Fixed on commit [505a6bcbf2f3a9d697861bf8025c85b0b52c122b](https://github.com/jetbrains/kotlin/commit/505a6bcbf2f3a9d697861bf8025c85b0b52c122b).